# select columns based on multiple values

Tags: sql

I have data which looks like:

```
data.csv
company  year  value
A        yz    x
```

I wan't to grab all columns when value is < x and year is 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 etc.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE value < "X" AND year ="2005" AND year="2006" AND year="2007" AND year="2008";
```

Above results in nothing. So essentially: give me all companies for which value has been below X the last YZ years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a condition that can never be true. It can't be 2005 and 2006 at the same time.

Try `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   data
WHERE  value < "X"
AND    year in ("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008")
;
```

The `in` checks whether `year` is one of the values following.

Or `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   data
WHERE  value < "X"
AND    ( year = "2005"
         or year = "2006"
         or year = "2007"
         or year = "2008"
       )
;
```

The `or` just checks whether the left side *or* the right side condition is true.

Comment: Cheers but this doesn't really give me what I want. I want the results from companies who have had a value < X the entire time period between YZ1 and YZ2. So I don't want companies who had a value < X for only one of these years.

Comment: The query checks the `value < "X"` for every year. Do you mean you want to check on the total?

Comment: Yeah extactly. I should just flip it around? I want for instance:

company A has had value below X for a total of 13 years, the time period in my data.

company B has had a value below X for a total of 11 years.

I want the result to show me company A but not company B.

Comment: That is a very difficult task since you need the accumulating sum of a field and also compare it to the result of others... This goes much further than your current question. I would suggest to ask a new question explaining all the details you want, your database platform, etc.

Comment: Ah, maybe I was a bit stressed and didn't think this through. I'll post a new one :) Any suggestions on a headline? cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244467/sqlite-sliding-to-get-results-based-on-value-and-date

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE value < "X" AND YEAR IN (2005, 2006, 2007, 2008)
```

Comment: This does answer the question, but you could add a bit more context on how IN works, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to change a string format from a year to a datetime, then you can simply select like this:

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE value < "X" AND year(year) >=2005;`

else you can use:

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE value < "X" AND YEAR IN (2005, 2006, 2007, 2008);`

Comment: I can easily convert to datetime, but this doesn't really give the desired output, see my post below @Patrick Hofman