# SQLite, sliding to get results based on value and date

Tags: sql, sqlite

This questions is posted on a suggestion in this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242333/select-columns-based-on-multiple-values)

I'm using SQLite/Database browser and my data looks like this:

```
data.csv
company  year  value
A        2000  15
A        2001  12
A        2002  20
B        2000  25
B        2001  20
B        2002  10
C        2000  18
C        2001  14
C        2002  22
etc..............
```

What I want to do is get all companies which have a value of <= 20 for all years in the data set. Using above data this would mean I want the query to answer me:

```
result.csv
company    year   value
A          2000   15
A          2001   12
A          2002   20
```

Thus excluding company C due to value > 20 in 2002 and company B for value > 20 in 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all companies whose maximum value is no larger than 20:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE company IN (SELECT company
                  FROM Data
                  GROUP BY company
                  HAVING max(value) <= 20)
```

Comment: Cheers for answer, but please re-read the question posted. I want companies who have never had a value larger than 20 for the last X years, in total. 

For above I could also use

SELECT * FROM data WHERE value <= 20;

no?

Comment: You are right, optionally you could use a where clause in the inner query to filter the years.

Comment: @user3471881: No, the `max` prevents that. It will never have a row >= 20.

Comment: @user3471881 To understand it, try executing the inner query alone.

Comment: Ah! Sweet. Tried it now and this actually gives me the correct answer. But I don't really understand how it accomplishes this... Will play around :)

Comment: @user3471881 Look up GROUP BY and HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are better solutions, but I think this will work:

```
select company
,      sum(case when value < 20 then 1 else 0 end) s
,      count(*) c
from   data
where  year in (2000, 2001, 2002)
group
by     company
having s = c
```

It will check whether the count equals the number of years where the value is less than 20.